# how to send namespace in amazon-managed-prometheus via awscli

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, prometheus, aws-cli

I want send the PromQL query to amazon-managed-prometheus via awscli, But I am not able to filter result based on namespace.

I am able to send the same filter in local prometheus via prometheus_api_client.PrometheusConnect, but can not use the same in aws(because of auth)

Is there any way?

```
awscurl -X POST --region ap-southeast-1 --access_key $KEY1 --secret_key $KEY --service aps "https://aps-workspaces.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/workspaces/ws-2222-222-222-222-222/api/v1/query?query=sum(storage_level_sst_num) by (namespace, instance, level_index)"
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "resultType": "vector",
    "result": [
      {
        "metric": {
          "instance": "10.0.3.68:1250",
          "level_index": "0_MVGroup",
          "namespace": "benchmark"
        },
        "value": [
          1665730049.128,
          "8"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
 ~ %
s awscurl -X POST --region ap-southeast-1 --access_key $KEY1 --secret_key $KEY --service aps "https://aps-workspaces.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/workspaces/ws-2222-222-222-222-222-2222/api/v1/query?query=sum(storage_level_sst_num{namespace="benchmark"}) by (instance, level_index)"
{"message":null}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/bin//awscurl", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('awscurl==0.26', 'console_scripts', 'awscurl')())
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/awscurl/0.26_1/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/awscurl/awscurl.py", line 521, in main
    inner_main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/awscurl/0.26_1/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/awscurl/awscurl.py", line 515, in inner_main
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/awscurl/0.26_1/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 953, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://aps-workspaces.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/workspaces/ws-2222-222-222-222-222-2222/api/v1/query?query=sum(storage_level_sst_num%7Bnamespace=benchmark%7D)%20by%20(instance,%20level_index)
```